# RSYNC - Ignore a Directory on destination box

Tags: linux, rsync

I am performing a dry run using Rsync on 2 different boxes.

While i'm doing that, Under destination directory, I want a specific directory x to be ignored for sync.

Please let me know the exact pattern to ignore the directory.

The current command I'm  using is:

```
rsync -avnc --delete $LOCAL_DIR $USERNAME@$DESTINATION_IP:$REMOTE_DIR
```

under `DESTINATION_IP`, I would want to ignore a particular directory under REMOTE_DIR.

Answer (score 1):

If you looked at the arguments for rsync, you would have seen:

```
--exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN
```

So with that, I would suggest the following dry run:

```
rsync -avnc --delete --exclude=x $LOCAL_DIR $USERNAME@$DESTINATION_IP:$REMOTE_DIR
```

cheers

sc.